# Font problem in pdftex

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I am designing a cover page for an online publication, and apparently, the pdf (created with pdftex from the file pasted in below) does not display correctly for some users. Part of the second line of the title are missing.

```
\documentclass[extrafontsizes,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{humanist}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{4cm}{5cm}% left, top
{4cm}{6cm} %right, bottom
{1cm}{0.7cm}%head height, sep
{0cm}{0cm}% foot height, sep
\usepackage{fourier-orns}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\noindent{\Huge\bfseries\hminfamily\color{red} Title of the Book\bigskip\\second line of title}\vspace{1.2cm}\\
{\small edited by}\medskip\\
{\large Name of the author}\vspace{1cm} \\\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2.2in]{cover1.jpg}
{\small
Somewhere 2012}\medskip\\{\color{Brown}\rule{2.5cm}{1pt}\aldine\rule{2.5cm}{1pt}}\bigskip\\
{\normalsize
Series title}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I would be very grateful for any help with the matter. Does this have anything to do with embedding fonts? The page looks fine here, and also other users who don't have the humanist font installed can view it without problems. I have heard from someone that the text displays correctly on the Acrobat Reader, but not on Foxit (on the same machine).

Comment: The humanist fonts are bitmap fonts (pk) which are always embedded in the pdf. Probably foxit has problems to display this fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done some more testing, and it appears that this error is specific to Foxit. (The second line begins with "B", which Foxit displays as "P".) Many thanks!